# ATLAS configuration failure under OSX

Tags: macos, atlas

I'm trying to install ATLAS 3.11.17 under OSX 10.9, when I run './configure' I get the following output:

```
James-Braithwaites-MacBook-Pro:bld jamesbraithwaite$ ../configure -b 64 --shared --prefix=/usr/local/atlas3.11.17 \
>     --with-netlib-lapack-tarfile=../../lapack-3.5.0.tar 
make: `xconfig' is up to date.
./xconfig -d s /Users/jamesbraithwaite/Desktop/tmp/atlas3.11.17/bld/../ -d b /Users/jamesbraithwaite/Desktop/tmp/atlas3.11.17/bld  -b 64 -D c -DATL_DYLIBS -Si lapackref 1

OS configured as OSX (12)

Assembly configured as GAS_x8664 (2)

Vector ISA Extension configured as  SSE3 (6,448)

Architecture configured as  Core2 (25)

Clock rate configured as 2400Mhz

Maximum number of threads configured as  2
Parallel make command configured as '$(MAKE) -j 2'
Cannot detect CPU throttling.
rm -f config1.out
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make atlas_run atldir=/Users/jamesbraithwaite/Desktop/tmp/atlas3.11.17/bld exe=xprobe_comp redir=config1.out \
                args="-v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 12 -A 25 -Si nof77 0 -V 448   -b 64 -d b /Users/jamesbraithwaite/Desktop/tmp/atlas3.11.17/bld"
cd /Users/jamesbraithwaite/Desktop/tmp/atlas3.11.17/bld ; ./xprobe_comp -v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 12 -A 25 -Si nof77 0 -V 448   -b 64 -d b /Users/jamesbraithwaite/Desktop/tmp/atlas3.11.17/bld > config1.out
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mfpmath=sse'
/bin/sh: line 1:  4192 Segmentation fault: 11  ./xprobe_comp -v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 12 -A 25 -Si nof77 0 -V 448 -b 64 -d b /Users/jamesbraithwaite/Desktop/tmp/atlas3.11.17/bld > config1.out
make[1]: *** [atlas_run] Error 139
make: *** [IRun_comp] Error 2
ERROR 512 IN SYSCMND: 'make IRun_comp args="-v 0 -o atlconf.txt -O 12 -A 25 -Si nof77 0 -V 448   -b 64"'
mkdir src bin tune interfaces
mkdir: src: File exists
mkdir: bin: File exists
mkdir: tune: File exists
mkdir: interfaces: File exists
make: *** [make_subdirs] Error 1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Make.top startup
Make.top:1: Make.inc: No such file or directory
Make.top:325: warning: overriding commands for target `/AtlasTest'
Make.top:76: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/AtlasTest'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Make.inc'.  Stop.
make: *** [startup] Error 2
mv: rename lib/Makefile to lib/Make.tmp: No such file or directory
../configure: line 450: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 451: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 452: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 453: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 471: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 472: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 473: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
../configure: line 509: lib/Makefile: No such file or directory
DONE configure
```

What is causing this problem and how do I fix it?

I'm needing to install ATLAS as it is a dependancy for Sextractor.

Thanks for your help in advance!

James

Answer (score 0):

It is now fairly easy to install sextractor without ATLAS using homebrew:

1. Install `homebrew` from http://brew.sh/
2. Tap the science formulae with `brew tap homebrew/science`
3. `brew install sextractor` will build and check sextractor.